# Where will I be on my route at a certain time?

Tags: google-maps, gps, waze

Is there a way in Waze (or any other mapping app) to see where I will be on my current route at a certain time?

For example, I want to know roughly where I'll be at 7 am at my current rate with current and projected road conditions (I know the second half is asking a lot).

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible in Waze to know roughly where you'll be at a given time given your current rate, put aside the ETA.

Comment: " put aside the ETA."  Are you saying the ETA is inaccurate?  Or are you saying the ETA calculations don't factor in road conditions well?

Comment: @WalterStabosz I meant: the ETA only indicate roughly where you'll be at the ETA time, but if you want to know where you'll be at some other times, then Waze won't tell you.